# Can I use buildozer for non-kivy python scripts

Tags: python

I wanna know if i can use buildozer for non-kivy python scripts. Is it possible to build apk files from ordinary python scripts other than kivy scripts?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it probably isn't possible. However, you should ask in the [kivy support group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/kivy-users). You need to join it to post. Some people there really seem to know their kivy, and in my experience, I haven't had to wait too long for answers.

**EDIT:**

If you look in the buildozer.spec file of your project, you will see the following lines are included by default:

```
# (list) Application requirements
requirements = kivy
```

While this makes it seem like kivy may be a requirement for all projects with buildozer, you could try commenting out the requirements or something and see what happens when you try to compile code without kivy.

Or since that is a bit of a backwards way to do it, as you would have to have already created your buildozer.spec file. Perhaps you could just try using buildozer on a project without kivy and see what happens.